# Does this not work because I can't use a script in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, script-tag

I am making a website with a program editor, for users to make HTML programs.
I usually test this out by inputting `<script> alert("Hi!"); </script>` into the `body` input area, but no alert comes. As you can see from the code, the result is the script ending up inside the `div`.
So do `script`s work in `div`s? If they do, here's my code (the important part, at least):

This is my script to run when I press the "Run!" button:

```
<script>
    function onclick(){
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")["0"].innerHTML += eval(document.getElementById("editorHead").value);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = eval(document.getElementById("editorBody").value);
    }
</script>
```

This is the code for the input areas & run button (omitting the text between them & class attributes):

```
<textarea id="editorHead" rows="20"></textarea>
<textarea id="editorBody" rows="20"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
<button onclick="onclick();">Run!</button>
```

I tried changing the `onclick`'s name to `run`, and that made the clicking work (before that the button wouldn't turn blue when you clicked it), but that was it.

Comment: Try putting the `<script>` beneath the `body`

Comment: doesn't work because `onclick` is a window function....you are interfering with it by naming yours the same

Comment: @Zeaklous Thanks for the suggestion!
@charlietfl I said I tried changing `onclick`s name to `run`.

Comment: rename your function to myOnclick so you don't overload window.onclick.

Comment: name it something descriptive like `dangerousEval()`

Comment: What charlietfl said. You kinda answered your own question though since you observed that changing the name makes it work.

Comment: @ithcy @Plato @DeepThought Guys! Nothing about `window.onclick`!

Comment: Phew. @DeepThought changing the name does NOT make it work. It only makes the clicking work!

Comment: @raumaankidwai you named your function `onclick` in the global scope, which is the `window` scope. Therefore your function *becomes* `window.onclick`.

Comment: @ithcy I said in the end that changing the name only fixed clicking.

Answer (score 1):

The asked question is do scripts work in div's.  Yes <script></script> tag content executes inline where it appears in the document.

However, it always executes in the document context.  Meaning this === document.  So to bind to the div's onclick method (the way you handle ui events in javascript) you need to find the div :

```
document.findElementById("my-div-id").onclick = function(e) {
   // do something
};
```

Note this clobbers the default behavior for the element if there is a default click behavior (like on an a tag)

Also to be more clear on the expected behavior.  Do this

```
<script>
    function doSomething() {
        alert();
    }
</script>
<button onclick="doSomething()">Button</button>
```

Comment: I cleaned it up and added an example of how to get a function bound to an event on a dom element.  Personally I prefer binding functionality in javascript via my example above rather than the one below.  But it is easier to understand when introspecting a live html document with developer tools in chrome or firebug.

Comment: Finally I recommend using jQuery or dojo, etc.  for convenience functions like dojo.hitch which will bind one function to another.  This way you don't clobber existing behavior (like doing some validation before posting in a form).