# Should I use .innerHTML or .value for <textarea>?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is a follow-up of [Does this not work because I can't use a script in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963781/does-this-not-work-because-i-cant-use-a-script-in-a-div)

Where I left off, I had this code:
Button script:

```
<script>
    var correctProperty = "value";
    function run(){
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")["0"].innerHTML += eval(document.getElementById("editorHead")[correctProperty]);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = eval(document.getElementById("editorBody")[correctProperty]);
    }
</script>
```

The textareas (without `class` and `style` attributes & in between non-div text):

```
<textarea id="editorHead" rows="20"></textarea>
<textarea id="editorBody" rows="20"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Currently this doesn't work, and one of my answers from before (the accepted one) said that `correctProperty` should be set to `"innerHTML"`. So should it? Or is the problem an interference with `window` (like before)? Or, ... should I put it in a form and then use `"value"`?

Comment: The main thing **not** to use is `eval()` here.

Comment: @Pointy I know it's **not** the problem. That's given.

Comment: That answer to the other question is wrong.

Comment: @Pointy check your notifications

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do here?  [Here is the MDN documentation for the textarea element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextareaElement) and you can see that the "value" property is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You access and update the value of a textarea element through the "value" property.

Try:

```
 var theValue = document.getElementById("editorHead").value;
```

Updating the `<html>` element doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @raumaankidwai your code doesn't work for other reasons, including the odd use of `eval()`.

Comment: "odd use of `eval()`" is the ***_only_*** way to do it, period.

Comment: Prove it. I challenge you.

Comment: I did **NOT** update the `html` element, I updated the `head` tag.
If I didn't, the user wouldn't be able to add CSS.

Comment: @raumaankidwai well you're the one here having the problem :)  The update to my answer shows how you get the "value" property of a `<textarea>` DOM element. [Here is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/YW2Ty/)

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("html")["0"]` will give you the document element, not the `<head>`.

Comment: That was not what I meant. Oops. I'll fix that now.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript innerHTML does update the text in textarea but it doesn't show yours changes in the browser window; if you use it for the second time. for example, If you had some button that updates the text in textarea; this button would insert text for the first time but on second time although it would insert text in textarea (as can be proved by firebug or chrome developer tool) but this would not be shown in browser window. Instead if you use value this would be shown in browser (I had test it in chrome and firefox).

So I think you should use .value

Comment: I was looking for an explanation for this problem (+1).

Answer (score -1):

No idea why you are using eval... below is corrected.. outside of that not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  Both value and innerHTML will pull from textareas, the question is what you want only text in the return or possible HTML values.

```
function run(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML += document.getElementById("editorHead").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("editorBody").innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Except `.innerHTML` is not the way you get the value of a `<textarea>` element.

Comment: I assure you .innerHTML will pull the html from inside a <textarea> element, as will .value.  The use of either is not the source of the OP's problem in the example.

Comment: It will not pull any updated content when a user types into the input field however. Try it if you don't believe me.