# How to find a varible html element executing javascript in python

Tags: javascript, python, bots, recaptcha, 2captcha

I'm trying to use 2Captcha service to solve an h captcha V2.

Works like this:

1. you get a value to solve the captcha
2. Then you find a textarea element in the HTML code to insert that value (here's my problem)
3. you insert the value in that element
4. You press submit button and the captcha is solved

First I'm going to present a working example, then I'll present where I have the problem.

This is the HTML code to find and insert the obtained value:

```
textarea id="h-captcha-response" name="h-captcha-response" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

This is the python code used to insert the value:

```
value = get_value()
insert_solution = 'document.getElementById("h-captcha-response").innerHTML="' + value + '";'
driver.execute_script(insert_solution)
```

What this exactly does is taking you from this:
[image]

and this is the result:
[image]

Finally you press the submit button and it's done. This example works

This is my problem:
In my case the HTML document has a variable ID, like this one:

```
<textarea id="h-captcha-response-0tesbrpxsk8" name="h-captcha-response" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

Notice that the id has an alphanumerical part (0tesbrpxsk8) that always changes making it more difficult to select.

I tried to find some regular expression to use inside of `document.getElementById()`
With no success

I also tried to use:

```
document.getElementByTagName("textarea").innerHTML=".....
```

I'm stucked here and tried other approaches with no success because I probably because I don't implement well those solutions or they just don't work.

I'll appreciate some insights, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fill out all of those (recaptcha / hcaptcha):

```
driver.execute_script('''
  let [captcha] = arguments
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[name="h-captcha-response"],[name="g-recaptcha-response"]')].map(el => {
    el.innerHTML = captcha
  })
''', value)
```

Comment: I get this error `selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unexpected token '...'
` I tried without the ... but then raises another syntax error

Comment: Yes it works, apparently there's a cloudlflare that do other things in the back so it was difficult to see results. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('[id^="h-captcha-response-"]')
textarea.value = "This is inside the textarea!"
```

```html
<textarea id="h-captcha-response-0tesbrpxsk8" name="h-captcha-response"></textarea>
```

- First of all: You set the value of an textarea with `textarea.value = "some value"`
- You should use `document.querySelector()` to select elements. (You have much more abilities there)
- You can select id starting with, with this query: `[id^="start"]`

Comment: Yeah using querySelector() seems more flexible to do this, thanks, but mind that I'm using python,
I tried this instead: `insert_solver = 'document.querySelector(\'[id^="h-captcha-response-"]\').innerHTML="' + result + '";'`
`driver.execute_script(insert_solver)`
NO success

Comment: @V-cash Replace `innerHTML` with `value` like wrote in my answer.

Comment: @pguardiario You should use .value as refereed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986290/should-i-use-innerhtml-or-value-for-textarea/27898249

One reason why it's not working is some other javascript from the captcha. I'm sure google is protecting this easy manipulation in some way.

Comment: No, value is the wrong property in this case. [innerText is recommended](https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#solving_captchas) but innerHTML works too

Comment: @pguardiario Alright, I'll modify my post. :) Didn't know that with captchas.